# How to prevent Web Resources Files From Being Downloaded in JSF

Tags: jsf

I have Embedded an applet inside xhtml tags which works fine but the problem is that when a user time the full application path plus the applet name, the user can comfortably download that applet (User should not Download).
I tried using this code in web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Prevent Applet from download</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Applet.jar</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/applet.jar</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

Above prevent the applet from being downloaded however it prevent the applet from being accessed xhtml tags. How Can I achieve this either using filter or web.xml config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An applet is needed by the client so it can run **on the client**. Preventing it to be downloaded makes the whole application non-functional. If you implement a normal authentication in a webapplication, the applet will be protected to.

Comment: So there is no way I can prevent it from being downloaded from URL(GET)

Comment: Yes, but than the client can never have access to the applet. Applets run **in the client browser**. That would be the same as you removing the applet from the server after which this whole question becomes superfluous

Comment: Ok. How else can I access user pc  recources/ read connected devices in java apart from applet

Comment: That is a new question and not related to this one. And I think there are multiple Q/A to be found on this on the internet... The answer above is the answer to the initial question. ;-)